# Python - How To Rename A Text File With DateTime

Tags: python, datetime

I'm using Python v2.x and am wondering how I can rename a known text file, for my example say "text.txt", to include the current date and time.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To get the current datetime use:

```
import datetime
dt = str(datetime.datetime.now())
```

Then to rename file:

```
import os
newname = 'file_'+dt+'.txt'
os.rename('text.txt', newname)
```

Comment: The produced string is not a valid filename in windows.

Comment: agree..not valid on windows

Answer (score 31):

`os.rename("text.txt", time.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S.txt"))`. Note that you have to `import` `os` and `time`.

Have a look over [here](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.strftime) for time stuff and over [here](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.rename) for renaming files.

Answer (score 1):

[os.rename(src, dst)](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.rename)

```
import os
import datetime

src = '/home/thewoo/text.txt'
dst = '/home/thewoo/%s-text.txt' % datetime.datetime.now()
os.rename(src, dst)
```

Modify `dst` and [strftime](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) the date as required.

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
import datetime

timestamp = datetime.datetime.now() 
t = timestamp.year,timestamp.month,timestamp.day,timestamp.hour,timestamp.minute,timestamp.second 

split_filename = filename.split('.')
os.rename(filename, split_filename[:-1] + '_' + '-'.join(t))
```