# Using Python to extract data if a terminating line is present

Tags: python, python-2.4

I'm currently trying to extract some data between 2 lines of an input file using Python.
the infile is set up such that there is a line -START- where I need the next 10 lines of code if and only if the -END- condition occurs before the next -START-. The -START- line occurs many times before the -END-. Heres a general example of what I mean:

blah
blah
-START-
10 lines I DONT need
blah
-START-
10 lines I need
blah
blah
-END-
blah
blah
-START-
10 lines I dont need
blah
-START-

.... and so on and so forth

so far I have only been able to get the -START- + 10 lines for every iteration, but am at a total loss when it comes to specifying the condition to only write if the -END- condition comes before another -START- condition. I'm a bit of a newb, so any help will be greatly appreciated.

Bonus: I need each block of START + 10lines to be printed to a new/unique outfile.
but I haven't really played around with that yet, so feel free to ignore this part.

heres the code I have for printing the -START- + 10 lines:

```
in = open('input.log')
out = open('output.txt', 'a')

lines = in.readlines()
    for i, line in enumerate(lines):
        if (line.find('START')) > -1:
            out.write(line)
            out.write(lines[i + 1])
            out.write(lines[i + 2])
            out.write(lines[i + 3])
            out.write(lines[i + 4])
            out.write(lines[i + 5])
            out.write(lines[i + 6])
            out.write(lines[i + 7])
            out.write(lines[i + 8])
            out.write(lines[i + 9])
            out.write(lines[i + 10])
```

Comment: Is it always exactly ten lines, or is it just "however far is it is between a START and an END, assuming no other STARTs between them"? Which of these termination factors (END or 10 lines) is most important?

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track. What you want to do is keep an eye on the list of lines that you've seen, and check them as they go: if you see another START before your ten lines are up, discard the current list and start fresh. So your loop looks something like this:

```
lines_to_write = []
for line in lines:
    if line.find('START') > -1:
        lines_to_write = [] # Empty anything that was in the list before
    if line.find('END')  > -1:
        out.writelines(lines_to_write) # Write all useful lines
        lines_to_write = []
        continue
    lines_to_write.append(line)
```

This is assuming that `END` always occurs in the right place. If you always want ten lines after the start, no matter what they are (as long as they aren't more `START` lines), then your second conditional would look like this instead:

```
if len(lines_to_write) == 10:
    out.writelines(lines_to_write)
    lines_to_write = []
    continue
```

To print each block to a new output file, just redefine `out` to a new output file after each time you call `out.writelines`. This way you only make as many new files as you need. To make them unique files, if there's no specific way you need to do that, just [add a timestamp to the filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218261/python-how-to-rename-a-text-file-with-datetime).