# Rename file name in python

Tags: python, file, rename

Im looking to rename a file which is always export(x).csv but the x can be a random number.

Id like to rename it with the date format YYYYMMDDHHMM.csv

```
import os

old_file = os.path.join("c:\", "export%")

new_file = os.path.join("c:\", "YYYYMMDDHHMM.csv")

os.rename(old_file, new_file)
```

Comment: To begin with, get rid of that backslash, either by replacing it with a regular slash, or by adding another one right next to it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - How To Rename A Text File With DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218261/python-how-to-rename-a-text-file-with-datetime)

Comment: "but the x can be a random number" What is the rule that tells you which file to rename? "Id like to rename it with the date format YYYYMMDDHHMM.csv" What is the rule that tells you the date and time to use for this name?

Answer (score 1):

If you want *YYYYMMDDHHMM* of the current day, you can use datetime:

```
s=datetime.today().strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M')
```

Note that:

- **%Y** = *Year*
- **%m** = *month*
- **%d** = *day*
- **%H** = *hours*
- **%M** = *Minutes*

You can also read [this](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/strftime). So, in your code:

```
new_file = os.path.join("c:/", s+".csv")
```

---

Just for example:

```
from datetime import datetime

s=datetime.today().strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M')
print(s)
```

will produce:

[image]